# How can i fix my functions in bash

Tags: bash

I am new to bash scripting have patience.
I have this code where it scans ports of domains and shows them to  the user and it works perfectly by it self but when i added functions to it gives me errors. What am I doing wrong here?

```
check_parms () {
case $# in
    1) ports='1-1023'
       host=$1 ;;
    2) ports=$1
       host=$2 ;;
    *) echo 'Usage: portscan [port|range] host'
       exit 1 ;;
esac
}

# check port range
check_ports () {
if [ "$(echo $ports | grep '^[1-9][0-9]*-[1-9][0-9]*$')" != "" ]; then
    firstport=$(echo $ports | cut -d- -f1)
    lastport=$(echo $ports | cut -d- -f2)
elif [ "$(echo $ports | grep '^[1-9][0-9]*$')" != "" ]; then
    firstport=$ports
    lastport=$ports
else
    echo "$ports is an invalid port(s) value"
    exit 2
fi
}

# check firstport > lastport
check_order () {
if [ $firstport -gt $lastport ]; then
    echo $firstport is larger than $lastport
    exit 3
fi
}

# check host value
check_host () {
regex='^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$'
if [ "$(echo $host | grep '[A-Za-z]')" != "" ]; then
    response=$(host $host)
    if [[ "$response" =~ "timed out" || "$response" =~ "not found" ]]; then
        echo host $host not found
        exit 4
    fi
elif [[ ! $host =~ $regex ]]; then
    echo $host is an invalid host address
    exit 5
fi
}

# check if host is reachable using ping
check_ping () {
if [[ "$(ping -c 1 -W 2 -n $host)" =~ "0 received" ]]; then
    echo $host is unreachable
    exit 6
fi
}

# start the scan     
do_scan () {
echo -n "Scanning "
for p in $(seq $firstport $lastport)
do
    echo -n .
    x=$((echo >/dev/tcp/$host/$p) >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "$p open")
    if [ "$x" != "" ]; then  
        y="${y}
$x"
    fi
done
}

# show results of scan
show_results () {
echo -e "\n$y\n"
exit 0
}

check_parms $#
check_ports $ports
check_order $firstport $lastport
check_host $host
check_ping $host
do_scan $host $firstport $lastport
show_results
```

Comment: The place to start when putting together a good question is isolating your problem, so you can show only the smallest piece of code necessary to show the issue you're asking about. Using `set -x` to trace each command run and see where things first go wrong is a good place to start with that. See also http://sscce.org/ and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'd also suggest putting your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing the issues it finds.

Comment: In addition to the above advice, it looks like you had a working script, did one "big" rewrite of it, and discovered it didn't work ... In general, you want to keep a tight feedback loop, that means, change one (or just a few things), then immediately test, fix if something works, and continue.... That way it's usually much clearer where the error is.

Comment: For consistency with other networking tools, it would be better to switch the argument order: `portscan host port`. This would also coincidentally simplify the code, and also it is then trivial to adapt it to accept multiple discrete ports or ranges.

Answer (score 2):

The way you're passing and using function arguments doesn't make sense. The one I see that's blatantly wrong is the first:

```
check_parms () {
case $# in
    1) ports='1-1023'
       host=$1 ;;
    2) ports=$1
       host=$2 ;;
    *) echo 'Usage: portscan [port|range] host'
       exit 1 ;;
esac
}

#... then in the main program:
check_parms $#
```

To understand the problem, suppose the main script is run with two arguments: "5-50" and "10.10.10.10". The line `check_parms $#` runs check_params and passes the number of arguments (2) as an argument to it. Fine so far. Then in check_params, it runs `case $# in`, but at this point we're inside check_params, so `$#` refers to the number of arguments *passed to check_params*, not the number passed to the main script. check_params was passed only one parameter (the number 2), so `$#` is 1, and it executes the `1)` case, which sets ports to "1-1023" and host to "2". This is not what you wanted at all.

If you want check_params to be able to see the same parameters that were passed to the main script, you have to pass it those same parameters with `check_params "$@"`.

The arguments passed to the other functions simply don't appear to be used; this won't necessarily cause trouble, but it makes for confusing code (and confusing code breeds bugs). Consider, for example the check_order function. You pass it `$firstport` and `$lastport` as arguments (meaning that within check_order, `$1` is set to the value of `$firstport` and `$2` is set to the value of `$lastport`), but then you don't use those arguments inside check_order; instead you use `$firstport` and `$lastport` directly, ignoring the parameters. Since they're the same thing, it doesn't really matter, but if someone later tried to use it for something else (`check_order $currentport 1023`) it would check `$firstport` and `$lastport` rather than what it looks like it should be checking.

Solution: change the functions to use their arguments rather than accessing global variables directly. (Or use the global variables explicitly and stop pretending to pass them as arguments; but globals are generally bad, so this is the worse option.) Something like this:

```
check_order () {
if [ $1 -gt $2 ]; then
    echo $1 is larger than $2
    exit 3
fi
}
```